# How to access the methods of the controller from another function?

Tags: sapui5

So I am making a call to my xsjs using the promise interface of jQuery as follows in my onBeforeRendering method of my Controller named Questionnaire.controller.js which is binded to view Questionnaire.view.xml

```
onBeforeRendering: function() {jQuery.get("/prototype/OnlineQuestionnaire/getQuestionsAndResponseChoices.xsjs", {
            questionnaireResponseId: jQuery.sap.storage.get("QuestionnaireResponseId"),
            password: jQuery.sap.storage.get("Password")
        }).done(function(data){
     that.OnlineQuestionnaire.controller.Questionnaire.prototype.checkData(); 
}).fail(function(jqXHR){
            MessageBox.show(jqXHR.responseText, "ERROR", "Service Call Error");
        });
    },
    checkData: function(){console.log("Hi");
    }
```

In my .done() I wanted to access the checkData() method but I was not able to because I donot know how to call the controller's method. I tried various ways :

```
sap.ui.controller("OnlineQuestionnaire.controller.Questionnaire").checkData();
```

then I tired :

```
sap.ui.getCore().byId('Questionnaire').getController().checkData();
```

This returned me `undefined`. So I am still unable to figure out how do I get my controller and then call its method. But I found a workaround and made it work using following, first i defined `var that = this;` so now my that consists of window object and then I called following':

```
that.OnlineQuestionnaire.controller.Questionnaire.prototype.checkData();
```

But there should be simplier way and I am missing something out. Can anyone suggest a simplier solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to ensure that `this` points to your controller inside the done method. Please [read](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) about the special behaviour of `this` in JavaScript compared to other programming language.

```
jQuery.get("/prototype/OnlineQuestionnaire/getQuestionsAndResponseChoices.xsjs", {
    questionnaireResponseId: jQuery.sap.storage.get("QuestionnaireResponseId"),
    password: jQuery.sap.storage.get("Password")
}).done(function(data) {
    this.checkData(); 
}.bind(this)).fail(function(jqXHR) {
    MessageBox.show(jqXHR.responseText, "ERROR", "Service Call Error");
});
```

There are other solution, e.g. using a helper variablte `that` to preserve the original context but I don't like that, as it makes your code less readable.

I assume that checkData should do something with your data. Therefore you should pass them to the method:

```
this.checkData(data)
```

Comment: yes exactly I would like to perform some validation on the data and I would be passing it. I would give this a read.  I think I used the helper variable that to preserve window object but then accessing the method is complicated as I have to write this:
`that.OnlineQuestionnaire.controller.Questionnaire.prototype.checkData();` I would try with binding . Thank you

Comment: The bind worked perfectly. But I need to understand it properly. Thank you for the reply :)

Answer (score 2):

Well, if I understood you correctly, your problem is the lost context of the controller withing the **done** callback.

There are two ways to solve this:

1. do the

`var that = this;`

at the beginning of your **onBeforeRendering** function and inside the **done** callback just call:

`that.checkData();`

2. you can set the right context via native js function **bind**. It will look like the following:

`onBeforeRendering: function() {
        jQuery
            .get("/prototype/OnlineQuestionnaire/getQuestionsAndResponseChoices.xsjs", {
                questionnaireResponseId: jQuery.sap.storage.get("QuestionnaireResponseId"),
                password: jQuery.sap.storage.get("Password")
            })
            .done(function(data) {
                this.checkData();
            }.bind(this))
            .fail(function(jqXHR) {
                MessageBox.show(jqXHR.responseText, "ERROR", "Service Call Error");
            });
    },
    checkData: function() {
        console.log("Hi");
    }`

To undertand this stuff more, you can read any info about JS context, scope and closure terms, i.e. http://ryanmorr.com/understanding-scope-and-context-in-javascript/

Comment: I used the method number 1 you suggested by making that hold the window object it is weird. I will give try to the bind function.

Comment: The bind worked perfeclty thank you for your link also I will study it have not understood it properly yet. I accepted the matbtt answer because he commented first and stack doesnot let me accept two answers x(

Comment: **that** won't hold the window object, it will contain the link to the instance of the controller. Actually I would suggest to use the approach with **that** variable, becasue at the and of the day it will be more readable and understandable for other developers, in case of using nested function it will be a nightmare to identify which context is used in a particular function.

Comment: But if use that then I have to access the method in following way: `that.OnlineQuestionnaire.controller.Questionnaire.prototype.checkData();`
True this is easier to understand.

Comment: Nope, you can use the same way to call the method: that.checkData(); Because **that** variable will hold the link to the controller's instance, so **that** will be the same as **this** on the outer scope of your callback.

Comment: yes thats what i thought but was not working gave me error that.checkData() is not a function that's why I had to use the above full path to call the function.

Comment: Looks like you create everything via pure js (not via the XML view). If you provide your code sample via jsbin or jsfiddle, I can give more information. Becasue there are different ways to create views, controllers and it works a little bit differently.

Comment: I have my **views in pure xml** and my **controllers in pure js**.  I will try putting in jsbin or jsfiddle

Comment: I don't know how to put the things in jsbin or jsfiddle as my datasource is coming from backend.  That is the reason I replied so late.  But I would like to understand the problem.

Comment: You can make use of mockserver to emulate the backend calls (and create a demo app in plunker), but particularly in this case, it's not about the ajax call, it's a basics of how ui5 works.

Comment: okay then is it okay if I just show you my controller.js and the view.xml corresponding to that controller.

Comment: Below is the link:

http://jsbin.com/xelicil/1/edit?html,output

You can see in the link in the OnBeforeRendering() i make a jQuery.get call to my xsjs and in the done function I have to bind(this) because if I make use of `var this=that` I need to specify full path which I have commented in the done() you can check.

Comment: It looks like you code sample is broken, there is no "checkData" method and "OnlineQuestionnaire" controller at all, something is definitely missing.

Comment: There is checkData. Sorry I didnot paste properly. Also there are more methods in my controller but I added only these to jsbin because I felt these were more relevant to understand the problem. Let me know if you want me to add the remaining methods also. Here is the updated jsbin link with code
http://jsbin.com/xelicil/3/edit?html,output

Comment: I cannot see where you decalare "var that = this". In your case it should be done at the beginning of the "onBeforeRendering" function. After that your "that" will point to the instance of controller and "checkData" will be propertly called.

Comment: I think I did mistake here I declared `var that = this` globally between  `sap.ui.define([
 "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller",
 "sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel",
 "sap/m/MessageBox"
], function(Controller, JSONModel, MessageBox) {

 var questionnaireData;
 var that = this;
 Controller.extend("OnlineQuestionnaire.controller.Questionnaire", {`

Comment: Also I declare the other global variables here. Is this the right place to declare global variables like questionnaireData and that or I should declare it somewhere else ?

Comment: I understood a little bit now what you were trying to say and I am using `var that= this` in the beginning and I could access with that the particular methods without needing to write the complete path to call the function. :) thank you.